# Выбор только одного пункта

Tags: menu, qt

Есть меню, всплывающее при нажатии ПКМ. В нём есть пункты, которые можно выбрать. Как сделать так, чтобы при включении одного пункта гасли другие?

```
void GameWidget::rightButtonPressEvent(QMouseEvent * ev){
QMenu* popup = new QMenu(this);
connect(popup, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), SLOT(popupHidden()));
popup->addAction(this->firstAction);
firstAction->setCheckable(true);
popup->addAction(this->secondAction);
secondAction->setCheckable(true);
.............
popup->exec(ev->globalPos());
return;}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Вы все делаете правильно, однако достаточно кое-что добавить чтобы все заработало так как Вы хотите: воспользуйтесь классом `QActionGroup`

Например так:

```
void GameWidget::rightButtonPressEvent(QMouseEvent * ev)
{
  QMenu* popupMenu = new QMenu(this);
  QActionGroup *actionGroup = new QActionGroup(popupMenu);
  connect(popupMenu, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), SLOT(popupHidden()));

  actionGroup->addAction(this->firstAction);
  firstAction->setCheckable(true); // хотя бы одно действие должно быть активно
  actionGroup->addAction(this->secondAction);
  actionGroup->addAction(this->thirdAction);
  .............
  actionGroup->setExclusive(true); // переводим группу действий в эксклюзивный режим
  popupMenu->addActions(actionGroup->actions()); // добавляем в меню все действия сразу

  popupMenu->exec(ev->globalPos());
  return;

}
```

В данном случае только одно действие будет активно (т.е. свойство checked = true).

Более подробные сведения как всегда в справке Qt: [QActionGroup class reference](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qactiongroup.html)

**UPD:** к делу не относится, но заметил в Вашем коде ошибочку: потенциально это memory leak (я правда не уверен, надо смотреть весь проект и лучше всего под дебагом). Дело все в том, что экземляр класса `QMenu` создается в куче, но не удалется! (хотя конечно он удалится вместе с `GameWidget`). Более того, судя по всему, приведенный код - это реализация обработки нажатия клавиши мыши, то есть мы получим такое количество экземпляров класса `QMenu` в памяти сколько было нажатий на клавишу (что наверное не есть хорошо). Я бы предложил создавать экземпляр QMenu **не в куче, а на стеке**, чтобы таким образом он убивался сразу при выходе из обработчика. Проблем с методом exec() не возникнет поскольку согласно справке Qt:

> Executes this menu synchronously.

С учетом выше сказанного я бы переписал Ваш код так:

```
void GameWidget::rightButtonPressEvent(QMouseEvent * ev)
{
  QMenu popupMenu(this);
  QActionGroup *actionGroup = new QActionGroup(&popupMenu);
  connect(&popupMenu, SIGNAL(aboutToHide()), SLOT(popupHidden()));

  actionGroup->addAction(this->firstAction);
  firstAction->setCheckable(true); // хотя бы одно действие должно быть активно
  actionGroup->addAction(this->secondAction);
  actionGroup->addAction(this->thirdAction);
  .............
  actionGroup->setExclusive(true); // переводим группу действий в эксклюзивный режим
  popupMenu.addActions(actionGroup->actions()); // добавляем в меню все действия сразу

  popupMenu.exec(ev->globalPos());
  return; // здесь popupMenu будет удален, а вместе с ним и actionGroup 
}
```

Еще раз повторюсь, что не знаю Ваших требований, и, возможно, также решением будет
перенести объявление `QMenu* popupMenu` в члены класса `GameWidget` и создавать экземляр меню в конструкторе.

В целом, как бы там ни было - успехов Вам!

Comment: Если ответ решает задачу, пометьте его как правильный