# В QMenu созданным в дизайнере, не получается настроить нажатие одного элемента

Tags: qt

Пытаюсь сделать чтоб в меню была нажата только одна кнопка (остальные отжаты), но не удаётся.

Конечно можно написать интерфейс с нуля из редактора но у меня нет этой возможности.

Посему у меня вопрос, можно ли настроить в QAction что бы работали как радио кнопки (когда одна нажата другие отжаты) ?

Воспользовался конектом

```
connect(ui->action5,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action10,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action20,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action33_333,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action47_619,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action50,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action83_33,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action95_238,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action100,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action125,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action250,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action500,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action800,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
connect(ui->action1_M,SIGNAL(toggled(bool)),this,SLOT(only_action()));
```

**Но не получается "снять " флажок.**

```
void MainWindow::only_action()
{
    qDebug() << "тут 1";
    if(ui->action5->isEnabled()){
        qDebug() << "тут ";
        ui->action10->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action20->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action33_333->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action47_619->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action50->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action83_33->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action95_238->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action100->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action125->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action250->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action500->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action800->setDisabled(true);
        ui->action1_M->setDisabled(true);
    }
    if(ui->action10->isEnabled()){
        qDebug() << "тут 2";
    }
   ..............
}
```

Интерфейс сделан в дизайнере Qt Creator-а

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Попробывал сделать по этой [ссылке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/319135/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0/319160#319160) не вышло

```
      QActionGroup *actionGroup = new QActionGroup(&this);
//    QActionGroup AGroup;
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action5);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action10);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action20);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action33_333);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action47_619);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action50);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action83_33);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action95_238);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action100);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action125);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action250);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action500);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action800);
    actionGroup->addAction(ui->action1_M);

    actionGroup->setExclusive(true); // переводим группу действий в эксклюзивный режим
    MainWindow.addAction(actionGroup->actions()); // добавляем в меню все действия сразу
```

ошибка

```
   ошибка: lvalue required as unary '&' operand
   QActionGroup *actionGroup = new QActionGroup(&this);
                                                 ^
```

Comment: Вместо ``isEnabled`` и ``setDisabled`` по всей видимости нужно использовать ``isChecked`` и ``setChecked``. Но в Вашем случае, как писали ниже, проще использовать ``QActionGroup``

Comment: @Александр увы я не столь хорош что бы работать с QActionGroup ((( (у меня не выходит , я кинул все их в акшон груп а дальше че делать не знаю)

Comment: @Александр  `ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QAction::setEnabled()'
     if(ui->action5->setEnabled()){
                                ^`

Comment: А где Вы по ссылке увидели такую конструкцию? ``QActionGroup *actionGroup = new QActionGroup(&this);``. Замените на ``QActionGroup *actionGroup = new QActionGroup(this);``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, создайте `QActionGroup` и добавьте туда те `QAction`, которые должны вести себя как радиокнопки

Answer (score 0):

```
QActionGroup *AGroup =  new QActionGroup(this);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action5);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action10);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action20);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action33_333);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action47_619);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action50);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action83_33);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action95_238);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action100);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action125);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action250);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action500);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action800);
AGroup->addAction(ui->action1_M);

AGroup->setExclusive(true); // переводим группу действий в эксклюзивный режим
//    MainWindow.addAction(AGroup->actions()); // эта строчка лишняя она не нужна так как типа дизайнер все сам понимает
```

Добавил этот код (сверху) и отключил все конэкты (конэкты по сути не мешают просто я их испугался, да и ради частоты эксперимента убрал)